# replace all + with -

Tags: java

I am trying to replace a `+` character into a `hyphen` I have in my string.

```
String str = "word+word";
str.replaceAll('+ ', '-');
```

I tried using replace but it throwing an `exception`.Is there any other method to do this.

Comment: most likely due to the fact that '+' is a special symbol in regex

Comment: + is a special character in regular expressions. Just escape it.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\+", "-");
```

A few errors in your code :

- [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes strings, not chars
- the `+` char must be escaped as the first argument is a regular expression (and `\` itself must be escaped in java string literals)
- you must take the return of the function : as String is immutable the function doesn't change it but returns another string

Comment: And you escaped the escaping because, you know, java.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `replace`:

```
str = str.replace('+', '-');
```

This one doesn't work on regex but take characters as they are.

Also as you see you have to reassing value again to your `str` variable because `String` in Java are immutable. In this case method `replace` doesn't change current `String` (`str`) but create new one with replaced `+` to '-'.

Answer (score 1):

The `replaceAll` function takes a *regular expression* as its first argument. It so happens that `+` is a special character in regular expression language. Try replacing `+` with `\\+`. This will escape the plus sign, thus making the code to treat it like a normal character.

Also, the `replaceAll` method yields a string, so that will not work. Try doing:

```
String str = "word+word";
str = str.replaceAll("\\+ ", "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll´ is for regular expressions and strings are immutable. Use:

```
str = str.replace("+", "-");
```

instead...

Answer (score 0):

Use "" as opposed to '' in replaceAll.

String java.lang.String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the escape sequence you need to use,

You could simply do this.

```
str = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"), "-");
```

This will automatically escape the regex predefined tokens to match in a literal way